# JAR - Selenium Java TestNG Maven project's JAR file returns failure

Tags: java, maven, selenium, jar, testng

My TestNG projects consists of just one class containing two `@Test` methods and below is my `main` method inside my `Runner` class.

```
public class Runner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestListenerAdapter tla = new TestListenerAdapter();
        TestNG testng = new TestNG();
        testng.setTestClasses(new Class[] { MyTestNGClass.class });
        testng.addListener(tla);
        testng.run();
    }

}
```

The problem is running the main method as a Java application from Eclipse runs perfectly fine, but when I generate a JAR file from my project using the "Export" option in Eclipse, and try to run the JAR file using `java -jar MyJar.jar` it returns below error on console:

```
[TestNG] Running:
  Command line suite


===============================================
Command line suite
Total tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================
```

Below is the result in testng-results.xml generated inside test-output directory.

```
<exception class="java.lang.RuntimeException"><message>java.lang.NullPointerException</message><full-stacktrace>java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:143)
    at org.testng.internal.Parameters.handleParameters(Parameters.java:426)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.handleParameters(Invoker.java:1383)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.createParameters(Invoker.java:1075)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1180)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1198)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1123)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
    at com.agrostar.pushnotifications.Runner.main(Runner.java:13)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:78)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:72)
    at utils.GoogleSheetsInit.authorize(GoogleSheetsInit.java:68)
    at utils.GoogleSheetsInit.getSheetsService(GoogleSheetsInit.java:88)
    at utils.GoogleSheetsReader.getRowWiseData(GoogleSheetsReader.java:41)
    at com.agrostar.pushnotifications.PushNotificationSender.googleSheetsDataProvider(PushNotificationSender.java:85)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeDataProvider(MethodInvocationHelper.java:117)
    ... 18 more
</full-stacktrace></exception>
```

Below is the code of the class from which the exception is thrown.

```
package utils.Google;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.Sheets;
import com.google.api.services.sheets.v4.SheetsScopes;

public class GoogleSheetsInit {
    /** Application name. */
    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME =
        "Google Sheets API Java Quickstart";

    /** Directory to store user credentials for this application. */
    private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR = new java.io.File(
        System.getProperty("user.home"), ".credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-java-quickstart");

    /** Global instance of the {@link FileDataStoreFactory}. */
    private static FileDataStoreFactory DATA_STORE_FACTORY;

    /** Global instance of the JSON factory. */
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY =
        JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    /** Global instance of the HTTP transport. */
    private static HttpTransport HTTP_TRANSPORT;

    /** Global instance of the scopes required by this quickstart.
     *
     * If modifying these scopes, delete your previously saved credentials
     * at ~/.credentials/sheets.googleapis.com-java-quickstart
     */
    private static final List<String> SCOPES =
        Arrays.asList(SheetsScopes.SPREADSHEETS_READONLY);

    static {
        try {
            HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
            DATA_STORE_FACTORY = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            t.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(1);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Creates an authorized Credential object.
     * @return an authorized Credential object.
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static Credential authorize() throws IOException {
        // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in =
            GoogleSheetsInit.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secret.json");
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets =
            GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
                new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
                        HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
                .setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY)
                .setAccessType("offline")
                .build();
        Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(
            flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
        return credential;
    }

    /**
     * Build and return an authorized Sheets API client service.
     * @return an authorized Sheets API client service
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public static Sheets getSheetsService() throws IOException {
        Credential credential = authorize();
        return new Sheets.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();
    }
}
```

Please help.

Comment: Can you provide the full code for MyTestNGClass.java?

Comment: @optimist_creeper I've updated the post with the code of the class from which the exception is thrown, not for MyTestNGClass.java. Hope that helps.

Comment: I don't remember exactly but there are two ways to export JAR, one with dependency and one without. if you have exported wtihout, you need to have other dependent Jars in class path somewhere. or try to export with all dependencies.

Comment: Yeah, but I believe if I would have exported it without dependencies, then the JAR should have given a different error. In my case, I see a NPE.

Answer (score 1):

I think the NPE comes from `InputStream in = GoogleSheetsInit.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secret.json");`.

First, check if the `client_secret.json` is present in your jar at the expected place.

Then, you can try to replace the line by  `...getResourceAsStream("client_secret.json");`.

Comment: It seems there was something basically wrong with the way I was trying to build my Maven project into a runnable JAR. I'll post my solution as an answer. Thanks anyway!